# Test case utilizing Mockito is not returning expected String value

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have my set-up here @Before for my test case

```
r = RentACat.createInstance();
c1 = Mockito.mock(Cat.class);
        Mockito.when(c1.getId()).thenReturn(1);
        Mockito.when(c1.getName()).thenReturn("Jennyanydots");

c2 = Mockito.mock(Cat.class);
        Mockito.when(c2.getId()).thenReturn(2);
        Mockito.when(c2.getName()).thenReturn("Old Deuteronomy");
```

With my test case as

```
r.addCat(c1);
        r.addCat(c2);
        r.addCat(c3);
        
        //Execution Steps
        String ret = r.listCats();
        
        //Postconditions
        assertEquals("Return string is not equal to expected string with added cats", "ID 1. Jennyanydots\nID 2. Old Deuteronomy\", ret);
```

And this is my implementation of listCats();

```
    public String listCats() {
        // TODO
        StringBuilder retBuild = new StringBuilder();
        for(Cat c : cats) {
            if(c.getRented() == false) {
                retBuild.append(c.toString());
                retBuild.append("\n");
            }
        }
        return retBuild.toString();
    }
```

However, when I run this test case I am getting a return value of an empty string.
I have tried some things like changing my implementation `listCats();`
such that

```
    public String listCats() {
        // TODO
        StringBuilder retBuild = new StringBuilder();
        for(Cat c : cats) {
            if(c.getRented() == false) {
                retBuild.append(c.toString());
                retBuild.append("\n");
                return retBuild.toString();

            }
        }
        return retBuild.toString();
    }
```

However, when I run this I am only getting one of the cats as had expected with the observed values as `"Mock for Cat, hashCode: 10523xyz"`

What am I doing wrong within my `listCats()` method?

Comment: Where does `cats` come from?

Comment: Do you need to mock `getRented` as well?

Comment: `if(c.getRented() == false)` is degenerate. `if(!c.getRented())`

Comment: @Egor has a point. If it’s a `Boolean` it might be `null`.

Comment: Note you’re also calling `toString` not `getName` in your loop.

Comment: Cats is an object that with when we call toString() within our listCats(), we organize it such as public String toString() {
  if (bugInjectionOn) {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Injected bug for toString()");
  }
  return "ID " + id + ". " + name;
 }

Comment: @Egor no need to mock the default will be `false`

Comment: If `Cat` is a value object, don't mock it; just create one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because you need to define the `toString()` behavior also in the mocked object. The string you have seen it's the default `toString` version for the mocked object. you can define yours like below.

```
Mockit.when(c1.toString()).thenReturn("Jennyanydots");
Mockit.when(c2.toString()).thenReturn("Old Deuteronomy");
```

Notice: if the `Cat` class is just POJO object with getter/setter no need to mock it you just fill with whatever you want from the data

Comment: Thank you this is what I was missing

Comment: Glad to hear that :)